# Heroku toolbelt on windows config:add causes broken paths

Tags: windows, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Attempting to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH on my heroku rails app using the heroku toolbelt on windows wrongly substitutes the paths sent to the app.

Running the following using heroku toolbelt on windows:

```
heroku config:add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/app/vendor/phantomjs/lib

Setting config vars and restarting... done, v164
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: C:\dev\Git\local\lib;C:\dev\Git\lib;C:\dev\Git\lib;C:\dev\Git\app\vendor\phantomjs\lib
```

It seems the toolbelt is automatically replacing "/usr" with "C:\dev\Git\" (where msysgit is installed on my system). Obviously this breaks my heroku app because these paths do not make sense on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not a problem with Heroku toolbelt, it's [documented behavior by msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion) (I'm assuming you're running this in msysgit). You can either run the command in a different shell (eg. Powershell) or use '//' at the start of the path like this:

```
heroku config:add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=//usr/local/lib://usr/lib:/lib://app/vendor/phantomjs/lib
```

This won't cause  problems when the path is used on Linux.